# Player jumping animation not playing in unity2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I been having some problems with my Jump animation for a cupple of days know and I was wondering how to make it so when I press the key "SPACE", it will play my jump animation. I already have a bool function called isJumping in my animator  its just that I do not know how to call it in the scrpit to play my jump animation. I have tried many tutorials to find out my answer and most of them don't really explain that well on how to do it. I already have my walking animation set up its just I know need to know how to do my jump animtion.

`Image of my animator`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOy8t.png)

My code so far

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PM : MonoBehaviour
{


public float moveSpeed;
public float jumpHeight;
Rigidbody2D rb;
BoxCollider2D boxColliderPlayer;
int layerMaskGround;
float heightTestPlayer;
public Animator animator;

    void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    // Get the player's collider so we can calculate the height of the character.
    boxColliderPlayer = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    // We do the height test from the center of the player, so we should only check
    // halft the height of the player + some extra to ignore rounding off errors.
    heightTestPlayer = boxColliderPlayer.bounds.extents.y + 0.05f;
    // We are only interested to get colliders on the ground layer. If we would
    // like to jump ontop of enemies we should add their layer too (which then of
    // course can't be on the same layer as the player).
    layerMaskGround = LayerMask.GetMask("Ground");
}

    void Update()
    {
    float moveDir = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDir, rb.velocity.y);

    // Your jump code:
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && IsGrounded() )
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
    }
    animator.SetFloat("Speed",Mathf.Abs(moveDir));
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Simple check to see if our character is no the ground. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns <c>true</c> if the character is grounded.</returns>
    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
    // Note that we only check for colliders on the Ground layer (we don't want to hit ourself). 
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(boxColliderPlayer.bounds.center, Vector2.down, heightTestPlayer, layerMaskGround);
    bool isGrounded = hit.collider != null;
    // It is soo easy to make misstakes so do a lot of Debug.DrawRay calls when working with colliders...
    Debug.DrawRay(boxColliderPlayer.bounds.center, Vector2.down * heightTestPlayer, isGrounded ? Color.green : Color.red, 0.5f);
    return isGrounded;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how your animation tree is setup. For this to work, make transitions from your other states where if isJump is set to true, then it will transition from whatever state it is into jumping (except jumping of course), then exit your jumping back to entry or to idle or some other state at the time of the end of the jump makes the most sense. If you post an image of your tree I can help you with this if needed.

With a transition and separate state setup with a bool to trigger the transition, the only code needed to make the animation play should be:

```
animator.SetBool("isJumping", true);
```

Once you detect in your isGrounded function that the player is grounded again, use the same snippet but pass in false to stop the jump animation.

```
animator.SetBool("isJumping", false);
```

Comment: I'm wonding were I put my animator.SetBool("isJumping", false); because if I put it in the privite isGrounded it wont work.

Comment: Your isGrounded is checking to see if you are grounded. Putting it in there will always make isJumping false. Only set isJumping when IsGrounded is false.